# for uwsim, how can I create two currents?

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For my project, I would like to make my scene in which two currents are generated in different directions. I thought having two oceanState tags would get this done, but it gave me an error.

Any method or resource I should know? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256405/for-uwsim,-how-can-i-create-two-currents?/) by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Unfortunately, it is not possible to create two oceanStates in UWSim, this is controlled by osgOcean that simulates the visual characteristics of the ocean thus it would require to modify osgOcean itself in order to be able to do it.

Anyway, this only controls the visual characteristics of the ocean, it has no effect in the vehicle physics that is controlled dynamically by underwater_vehicle_dynamics package when running a dynamic simulation as explained [here](http://www.irs.uji.es/uwsim/wiki/index.php?title=First_steps:_Dynamic_simulation). This node accepts an external forces input via ROS topic so you can add any perturbation force to it in order to simulation underwater currents for the vehicles.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on 2017-03-08**:
Hi Javier,

Thank you for the reply. Then do you know any references (like xsd) that I can use in order to build up my scene file?

**Comment by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) on 2017-03-09**:
Hi again,
Sorry if I did not explain myself correctly but this is something that CANNOT be solved just modifying the scene file. If you want to do it visually you need to modify the osgocean source. If you want currents that move the vehicle you need to implement them yourself through dynamics.